# Google Cloud get cluster credentials unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've created a service account in the IAM page of google cloud console but unfortunately I'm unable to assign roles to this account - or I'm missing something.

When attempting to get the cluster credentials for kubectl, GCloud always responds with the following:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials api --zone europe-west1-b --project *****
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission for "projects/*****/zones/europe-west1-b/clusters/api".
```

I've also added all the roles to the account as demonstrated here:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy project-tilas
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:travis@*****.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:travis@*****.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - user:Tj****n@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:travis@*****.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/viewer
etag: BwVqZB734TY=
version: 1
```

What am I missing?
Authentication is successful, and the project id/number's match up to what I see in the GCloud dashboard...

Comment: Take another close look at GKE quickstart in docs, ensure you haven't missed steps. Even better, repeat those steps, maybe it'll work or you will have more info to share.

Comment: I actually solved this late last night by completely removing the service account and recreating it... super weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a definitive answer, I actually solved this but just deleting the service account and recreating it.

Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, my fault is I was mentioning project name instead of project id. I solved the issue with:
`gcloud config set project <project_id>` 
and then:
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --zone=<zone>` 
Just thought about leaving this here as it may help someone in the future